# How to make plotly axes display only integer numbers

Tags: r, plotly

I have a plotly barplot in a shiny app, showing factor levels on X axis. But on some number of inputs (2,3,4) it shows marks like 1.5, 2.5 etc (see an image). So there is a question: can I somehow make the X axis marks show only integer values?

[image: sample]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`plotly` is guessing your axis types since your cluster labels are numeric.  You can fix this by coercing your x var to a factor before/when plotting.

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
mtcars_by_gear <- count(mtcars,gear)

plot_ly(mtcars_by_gear,
        x=~as.factor(gear), 
        y=~n)
```

If you want further control over axis labels you can use the `layout()` function's tick arguments, but the factor option seems better for your case.

```
plot_ly(mtcars_by_gear,
        x=~gear, 
        y=~n, 
        type="bar") %>% 
  layout(xaxis=list(tickvals=~gear,ticktext=~gear))
```

Answer (score 16):

**`tickformat=',d'`**

Supposing the attributes are the same as in Python where I tested :-), you can set:

```
layout(xaxis=list(tickformat=',d'))
```

where the valid values are D3 formats.

See also: https://community.plot.ly/t/restrict-axis-ticks-labels-to-only-show-int-values/3503/4

Comment: Thanks. Congrats on 1k answers btw!

Comment: It seems it's more complicated to handle this appropriately. Using tickformat will frequently result in duplicate labels (i.e. both 1 and .75 entries will show as 1).

Answer (score 2):

If using python:

```
fig = px.bar(df, x='x', y='y', title="Count")
fig.update_layout( xaxis={
    'range': [df['x'].min(), df['x'].max()], 
    'tickvals': [*range(int(df['x'].min()), int(df['x'].max()))]
})
fig.show()
```

Also you can force the axis to be categorical:

```
fig = px.bar(df, x='x', y='y', title="Count")
fig.update_xaxes(type='category')
fig.show()
```

Comment: in your code tickvals won't include max value. Add +1 to the max inside the range.